# How to use an SQL Comparator in the base 'Case' selector in the 'When' logic without having to re-write conditions

Tags: sql, case, sql-server-2016

I have an SQL query joined on multiple tables (all INNER JOINS).

The below is an example of the query I am trying to run (the **?** is to illustrate the position in which I presume the answer to my question will be rectified).

```
Case 
    (
        SELECT Count(ID)
        FROM CPD_Candidates cpdCan
        WHERE
            cpdCan.CandidateID = can.CandidateID
        AND
            (
                cpdCan.DateEnded >= GETDATE()
            OR
                coalesce(cpdCan.DateEnded, '') = N'1-Jan-1900'
            )
        AND
            cpdCan.Deleted <> 1
    )
    When ? > 0 then 'Bigger' else 'Equal or Smaller' End
)
```

The idea with the above is that instead of the **?** the actual value I want to compare against would be `Count(ID)`, if it's greater than 0 I want it to SELECT 'Bigger', otherwise it should SELECT 'Equal or Smaller'. So a *more-accurate* depiction of what I wish to run would be the below.

```
Case 
    (
        SELECT Count(ID)
        FROM CPD_Candidates cpdCan
        WHERE
            cpdCan.CandidateID = can.CandidateID
        AND
            (
                cpdCan.DateEnded >= GETDATE()
            OR
                coalesce(cpdCan.DateEnded, '') = N'1-Jan-1900'
            )
        AND
            cpdCan.Deleted <> 1
    )
    When 
         Count(cpdCan.ID) > 0 then 'Bigger' else 'Equal or Smaller' End
)
```

Of course there is a syntax error above but I am enquiring as to whether it is possible to compare like in the above SQL query structure but replacing `Count(cpdCan.ID) > 0` with some other means to achieve that value & logic?

If this is un-achievable in `SQL Server 2016` what other means would be a better solution to this `XY`?

Comment: The problem is your style of `CASE` expression, you are combining the 2 different ways of writing them. it is either `CASE {expression} WHEN literal THEN ...` or `CASE WHEN {boolean Expression} THEN...` You have combined these into `CASE {expression} WHEN {Boolean Expression}`. You need to move the subquery to *after* the `WHEN` not before it.

Comment: Don't use aggregation in a subquery when you intend `exists`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you mean:

```
case when
    (
        SELECT Count(ID)
        FROM CPD_Candidates cpdCan
        WHERE 
            cpdCan.CandidateID = can.CandidateID
            AND (cpdCan.DateEnded >= GETDATE() OR coalesce(cpdCan.DateEnded, '') = N'1-Jan-1900')
            AND cpdCan.Deleted <> 1
    ) > 0
    then 'Bigger' 
    else 'Equal or Smaller' 
End
```